# Bootstrap XS devices, iOS vs Android

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a webpage in bootstrap(V3). Everything is working fine, except the XS is not triggering on XS devices that are running android. Its working fine on iOS devices. How do I get XS to trigger on android but not mess up others.

When I used JS to check the screen sizes on android phones it says 980px.

Sorry if the question is not formatted correctly. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing the meta tag in the header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```